# Windows Key bindings from number pad

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I just installed Dexpot on Windows 7 to enable multiple desktops like I had on Linux Mint.  The keyboard shortcut for switching directly to desktop 2 is Alt + 2.  This doesn't work if iI press the number 2 on the number pad.  Why would that be a different key binding that Alt + 2 on the regular keyboard?

Is there a way to make Alt + 2 trigger the command from either 2 character?

Comment: try http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-do-i-change-the-windows-7-keyboard-shortcuts/0110d32d-66c0-4ce7-8682-eeb896e80c3f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to "Dexpot Settings > Controls > Hotkeys" and change the key bindings for the "Switch desktops" hotkeys to something else. If it works with the new hotkeys, Chrome, a Chrome add-on or some other application is intercepting the original Alt key combinations.

Comment: That's it!  Apparently CTLR+num 1, etc is the shortcut for switching to Chrome tabs. Learning all kinds of shortcuts today it seems.